# Losing image files saved by users after deployment updates to AWS

Tags: python, django, amazon-web-services

My Django App have a CRUD where users can save news with an image.

All my static files like banners and css files are working good. When the app is running and users create News, everything works fine too.

My problem starts when I need deploy updates to production. After deployment, the app is losing all image files uploaded by users. When users upload images, it are saved inside project folder and I think deployments are overwriting all project folder.

What can I do to solve this?

Some configs in my Settings.py which I think are important:

```
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'Setup/media')
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
DEBUG = False
```

I Already tried change the image path to outside project folder. But this don't work in production, because I don't have access to folders outside project in AWS.

Comment: You absolutely need to store images in S3 instead of anything local.

Comment: Or in [EFS](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/efs/latest/ug/whatisefs.html), which is a more "native" solution for a framework that expects filesystems.

Comment: OK Guys, I will test this tutorial
https://blog.theodo.com/2019/07/aws-s3-upload-django/